# How to initialise React Materialize Drop down after componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, materialize

My Navbar component doesn't have the Materialize Dropdown markup until a user signs in at which point I use conditional rendering and add the new markup. However I don't seem to be able to use `React.createRef()` to reference the new markup in order to initialise the Dropdown.
Please find a link to my project where you can create an account and [see the issue for yourself](https://qupp.2112staging.com).

What I think the problem is, is that I cannot recreate the ref after `compononentDidMount`.

I have tried creating the ref(`React.createRef()`) in `componentWillReceiveProps` and `componentWillUpdate` but I get a null value when I try to create the ref there.

```
class Navbar extends Component {
    userRef = React.createRef();

    render() {        
        const { isAuthenticated, user } = this.props.auth;

        // show these when logged
        const authLinks = (
            <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li className="avatar">
                    <a href="#" ref={this.userRef} data-target="dropdown1" className="dropdown-trigger">
                        <div className="avatar">
                        </div>
                        {user.username}
                    </a>
                    <ul id="dropdown1" className="dropdown-content">
                        <li><Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        );

        // show these when not logged in
        const guestLinks = (
            <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/register">Register</Link></li>
            </ul>
        );
        return (
            <nav>
                {isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks}
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
```

I need to reference the Dropdown DOM element when my Navbar receives new props(when the users successfully has signed in) so I can initialise it(`window.M.Dropdown.init(this.dropdownRef.current)`) when it has the right markup.

Comment: Where's the dropdown? I mean on which route because I'm not able to find it, meanwhile you can check this if this will help you - http://reactize.herokuapp.com/dropdown

Comment: Hi, on my app once you've created an account and logged in. Refresh the page and then the top right last menu item which will be your username is the dropdown. Will take a look at that link too.

Comment: P.s the dashboard route (https://qupp.2112staging.com/dashboard)

Comment: I see, what's the problem, it's not working by using ref and componentDidMount()?

Comment: When the component mounts there is no dropdown markup as it isn't needed then. When you login you're routed to the dashboard and the Navbar.js comp' gets new props and re-renders with the dropdown markup. However I cannot re-create or update the ref in order to initialise it with the proper markup.

Comment: I see, is there any repo of your code? So that I can check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193339/discussion-between-daniel-blythe-and-germa-vinsmoke).